# Privileges Error - CREATE DATABASE LINK Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a database with to Oracle Database. I used the Oracle Documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm) to write the below code to initiate the `CREATE DATABASE LINK` command, but am running into an issue. When I run this code (filling in username and password, of course), I am thrown an `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges` error.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK ITEMS
CONNECT TO username 
IDENTIFIED BY password
USING 'ITEMS'
```

Is there an issue with my code, or is it truly a permissions-related issue? How do I tackle this? I haven't used this command before, so I am wondering what needs to be accomplished.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the "create database link" system privileg granted to your user account as which you are trying to create?

Comment: I wasn't aware this was something to have on my user account, so probably not. I will make sure this is granted and try to run it again.

Comment: take a look in the documentation. Under Prerequisites.